# Java - Записать куки на все пути URL

Tags: java, cookie, servlet

В сервлете по URL - /user/registration регистрирую пользователя и записываю в его браузер куки.

```
Cookie nickCookie = new Cookie( "nick", user.getNick());
Cookie codeCookie = new Cookie( "code", user.getCode());
resp.addCookie(nickCookie);
resp.addCookie(codeCookie);
```

Вот так вот в сервлете записываю куки, но записывает только по URL - /user/registration.

Вопрос - как мне записать куки например на все пути что будут после `http://localhost:8080/user/*`

???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У класса `Cookie` есть метод `setPath()`. Он устанавливает куку для указанного каталога и всех подкаталогов

```
Cookie nickCookie = new Cookie( "nick", user.getNick());
nickCookie.setPath("/user");
Cookie codeCookie = new Cookie( "code", user.getCode());
codeCookie.setPath("/user");
resp.addCookie(nickCookie);
resp.addCookie(codeCookie);
```

Comment: Большое спасибо)